# Resharper - Disable 'help' when using "prop" shortcut in C#

Tags: c#, autocomplete, resharper, visual-studio-2015, resharper-9.2

I'm getting quite annoyed with a feature of Resharper that I just cannot find how to disable independently.

With Resharper turned off, whenever I type `prop` in VS2015 and press `TAB`, I get the following auto-generated code:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

and I'm then able to switch between `int` and `MyProperty` repeatedly by pressing `TAB` again.
I'm also able to use autocomplete to fill in the variable type as I type.

For example, lets say I wanted to create a property called "test" of type "string", I would do the following:

1. type `prop`
2. press `TAB` to generate the property code template
3. type `stri`
4. press `TAB` to autocomplete the variable type with `string`
5. press `TAB` to move to the variable name placeholder
6. type `test`
7. press `Return` to finish

perfect.

However, with Resharper enabled, whilst steps 1,2 and 3 still work, it all goes to pot after that!

If I press TAB to try and autocomplete the variable type, the cursor simply moves over to the variable name, leaving the variable type as `stri`.

If I then press `TAB` (or even `SHIFT+TAB`) again to try and get back to it, it simply finishes the line.

---

To make things clearer, I've included two gifs demonstrating my problem.

This first one shows what happens with Resharper disabled:
[image]

Whilst this one illustrates the frustration I'm currently experiencing with Resharper enabled:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an intellisense setting conflict. 
Re-Enable Resharper and then change this setting:

`Resharper->Options->IntelliSense->General`

Change the selection from "Visual Studio" to "Resharper", hit Save and the desired behaviour should be yours.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I understand this is an old(er) question and already has an answer; however, I wanted to provide a solution for future SO readers that would allow one to continue using Visual Studio's IntelliSense as opposed to Resharper's.

I had the same issue as the OP (original poster) and found the issue to be caused by a conflict with Resharper's Live Templates. With Resharper enabled, the resolution of `prop` after `Tab + Tab`, resolves Resharper's `prop` Live Template and not Visual Studio's `prop` snippet. You might have notice that in OP's 2nd screen cap (the one with Resharper enabled) that the resolution of `prop` has a datatype shown as `TYPE` instead of `int`. This is because Resharper's Live Template has set this parameter name to `TYPE`, while Visual Studio's snippet has the same parameter set to `int` by default. This is what lead me to look at Resharper's Live Templates for a resolution; lo and behold turning off the `prop` Live Template fixes the issue.

Go to Resharper's Template Explorer (`Resharper -> Tools -> Templates Explorer`) you will see there is a Live Template named `prop`. Simply clear the check box for the `prop` Live Template and Visual Studio's `prop` snippet resolution, and datatype resolution for that matter, will start working again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: and must you need uncheck .prop in Postfix Templates.

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour this solution and your solution doesnt work with the latest VS 2019 and resharper.

Answer (score 0):

I find those shortcuts still work without disabling anything however sometimes this functionality stops working.

Currently using R# 2018.2 with the default keyboard mappings set to IntelliJ IDEA scheme (as I also use java) and the shortcuts are all available, but when they stop working closing all tabs and reopening the tab you are working on normally fixes it.

No restart or reset is needed.